# What is the best way to prepad leading zeros in CAST coalesce row_number() over statement for sql server 2008r

Tags: t-sql

I have the 3rd column prepadding correctly but also need to prepad 0's for 9 characters on the second column. I have an example of a query that partially works. And I see several methods to prepad.

It needs to be in format

000001234
000123456

```
SELECT 'P', 
--coalesce-return the first nonnull expression, row_number-numbers all rows sequentially, over-defines a window
*[need to prepad here]* CAST(coalesce(xyz.MaxID, 0) as int) + row_number() over (order by(select NULL)) as theMax,
'P' + right('000000000'+ rtrim(CAST((CAST(coalesce(xyz.MaxID, 0) as int) + row_number() over (order by(select NULL))) as VARCHAR(50))), 9), 
T.ForeName, T.Middle_Name, T.Surname, '1234', 'n', GetDate(), GetDate(), 'SCT', '1', GetDate(), GetDate(), 'PGHERE', '1', 'n'
FROM INSERTED  i 
cross join 
--selecting max number between people or changes
(SELECT MAX(CAST(q1.Test as INT)) as MaxID FROM (SELECT MAX(CAST(PEOPLE_ID as INT)) as Test FROM pc.dbo.People WHERE CAST(PEOPLE_ID as int)<2000000 UNION ALL SELECT MAX(CAST(PEOPLE_ID as INT)) as Test FROM pc.dbo.Changes WHERE CAST(PEOPLE_ID as int)<2000000) q1) AS xyz
--used for testing since inserted table only exists in the context of the trigger when it's executing
CROSS APPLY dbo.Parser(i.Contact) T
WHERE i.Key1 = '23'
OR (i.Key1 = '45')
OR (i.Key1 = '67')
```

Comment: This is the only question on this forum about prepad leading zeros, with CAST, coalesce, row_number(), over statement. Why should it be downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`replicate(string expression, integer expression);`**

```
replicate('0', 9 - len(YourFieldName))
```

This will result in a field with 9 characters, with 0 preceding how many ever characters are missing from the total length of 9..

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't down vote it, but I believe there is a standard expectation on how a question should be formulated to best give you the answer you are looking for. Example, showing the output you are looking for, basic query to set up a schema that will help run the query you posted etc.. That might be the reason.